# Is $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ a group under multiplication when $n$ is prime?

Tags: associativity

I have to prove that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group under multiplication for all n>1. I would argue, however, that when $n$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a group under multiplication. Multiplication is associative, every element in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has an inverse when $n$ is prime, and the identity element is simply $\bar{1}$. What am I missing?

Comment: $0$ hasn't got an inverse.

Comment: oh. So then isn't it true that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group under multiplication for all $n$?

Comment: As lulu noted, $0$ has no inverse. Though, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ is a group

Comment: @Obliv That's a lot of negatives.  $\mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$ is never a group under multiplication because the element $0$ is never invertible.

Comment: how do I prove,then, that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group under multiplication? Do I simply show how 0 is not invertible and that 0 is in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for all n>1?

Comment: That looks like a proof to me.  We know $0$ is not invertible because $a\times 0=0\;\forall a\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you :)!

Comment: Z/nZ is never a group  Z/pZ-{0} is if p is prime.  Z/nmZ-{0} is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to be a group, we need that for every $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, to exist  $b \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a*b = 1$. But for $a = 0$, there is no $b$ such that $a*b = 1$, because $a*b = 0, \forall b \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a group!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it worth asking when is $(Z/nZ)^*$ a group under multiplication and the answer is precisely when $n$ is prime. Otherwise, $n=ab$ would imply that the product of the residue classes of $a$ and $b$ does not belong to $(Z/nZ)^*$

Comment: yeah but that doesn't change the fact that $0$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ regardless of what $n$ is. It'll never be a group as long as $0$ is in it.

Comment: True. That's why the question is not interesting. But the absence of $0$ makes things interesting.

Comment: The question may not be interesting but it *was* the question that was asked.  No amount of interesting is going to outweigh relevence, I'm afraid.  It's precisely your interesting case, that caused the OP trouble in the first place so reiterating it makes things worse.  Not to mention, the set you are talking about is NOT Z/nZ but (Z/n) - {0}.  That detail is *extremely* important.

Comment: By adding just a remark that concerns the real question of the OP you could make your answer complete.

Answer (score 0):

No.  But it is an cyclic additive group for all $n$.  And for each $n$ , you can consider the multiplicative group of units, $\Bbb Z_n^×$, which, for $p$ prime coincides with $\Bbb Z_p^*$, the multiplicative group of nonzero elements.